# Admob ad match rate sudden drop in August

Tags: android, admob, revenue

Does anyone's app **admob** ad match rate **suddently** drop that cause sudden revenue drop.

For one of my apps match rate suddenly drop in August 1st onwards. Receiving 1,50,000 ad request and match rate is only 7.46%, results only 6500 impressions.

Is it a common issue right now. There is no update in Admob policy center too

Comment: I've just experienced a significant drop in my match rate (100% -> 50% or so) very quickly this March. Has anyone else experienced this recently?